# Pandas: Convert the dateformat of an entire column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas column df["date"] that provides output like 43374.11, meaning it starts counting from 1900-01-01.

I would like to convert that column to YYYY-MM-DD format.

I tried the following code:

```
date_conv= datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) +
datetime.timedelta(int(df["date"]))
df["date"] =   date_conv.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

However, I get the following error:

> TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to apply a function meant for a single value (*Int*), to an entire column of values (*df["date"]*).

Try using the *apply* method to transform each value, one at a time, by calling a function like this:

```
def convert(d):
  dt = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(d)
  return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(convert)

print(df)

#          date
# 0  2018-10-03
```

Comment: Or make use of datetime accessors, eg: `(pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(df['date'], unit='D')).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need

```
pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.date, unit='d')+pd.to_datetime('1900-01-01')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-03 02:38:24', '2015-05-17 00:00:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```